# Unresolved Symbol: __except_handler4_common

Tags: visual-studio, exception

When linking my win32 app using MSVC2019, I get the error message

```
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __except_handler4_common
```

This was addressed a long time ago by SO #31867018, but the answer there was to make sure the /MTd was specified in Props->C/C++->CodeGeneration->RuntimeLibrary. My app *does indeed* specify /MTd so I'm at a loss to understand the problem.

I was able to make this error go away by including an empty version of this function in my app, e.g.,

```
void _except_handler4_common(void){}
```

but I am not enamored with such a gross hack :(

Comment: That symbol can only occur in code compiled with /MD in effect.  Breaking exception handling is not a good idea.  Typically it is code in a library you link, consider to adopt /MD for all the code.  The linker's /verbose option can be helpful.

Comment: Hans, Can't use /MD for all code - it breaks other things, but thanks for the comment

Comment: Hans, amplifying: my project uses some third party libs for which I don't have source code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to make this error go away by including an empty version of this function in my app, e.g.,

```
void _except_handler4_common(void){}
```

Admittedly, this is a gross hack. The "right" solution is to recompile all components with consistent /MD /MT settings.
But in my case third party libraries are used for which I don't have source code.
As Hans Passant pointed out, this is *not*, in general a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was just missing `vcruntime.lib`. To fix that go to “Configuration properties” > “Linker” > “Input” and add the library name to “Additional Dependencies“